# Public function that traverses through a tree

Tags: java, tree

So I have this function that lets one traverse through a tree without having to get the root node of the tree. The user basically sends a parameter that is either `Movement.LEFT` or `Movement.RIGHT` that specifies where to move to. It then returns the current node it is on. If the current node is a leaf, the tree traversal starts back in the root.

```
public HuffmanNode traverseNode(Movement direction)
{
    currentNode = (currentNode.isALeaf()) ? root : currentNode;
    currentNode = (direction == Movement.LEFT) ? currentNode.getLeftChild() : currentNode.getRightChild();
    HuffmanNode retrievedNode = currentNode;

    if (currentNode == null) currentNode = root;

    return retrievedNode;
}
```

Here's the code for the Huffman node.

```
package app.utils.ds;

public class HuffmanNode
{
    private HuffmanNode leftChild;
    private HuffmanNode rightChild;
    private HuffmanNode parent;
    private int colorValue;
    private int frequency;

    public HuffmanNode(int colorValue, int frequency)
    {
        this.colorValue = colorValue;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public void setParent(HuffmanNode parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void setLeftChild(HuffmanNode child)
    {
        leftChild = child;
        if (leftChild != null) {
            frequency += leftChild.getFrequency();
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    public void setRightChild(HuffmanNode child)
    {
        rightChild = child;
        if (rightChild != null) {
            frequency += rightChild.getFrequency();
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    public HuffmanNode getParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }

    public HuffmanNode getLeftChild()
    {
        return leftChild;
    }

    public HuffmanNode getRightChild()
    {
        return rightChild;
    }

    public int getColorValue()
    {
        return colorValue;
    }

    public boolean isALeaf()
    {
        return (leftChild == null) && (rightChild == null);
    }

    public int getFrequency()
    {
        return frequency;
    }
}
```

The code seems fine but I have a gut feeling that this might have code smells and can still be improved. How else can I improve this?

Comment: We could use some more code like the rest of the HuffmanNode class to give better advice on how to improve the method.  What is the current use for this method exactly?  Note that if you go left and reach the leftmost child in the tree, and then keep calling `traverse(LEFT)` you keep switching between that leaf node and it's parent.

Comment: @lmus, I updated the question.